# How to translate a mathematically described algorithm to a programming language?

Tags: algorithm

Given an algorithm, described in a paper of your choice with a bunch of symbols and a very special notation.
How do I learn to read such algorithm descriptions and turn them into a computer program?

The following picture describes an algorithm to calculate the **incremental local outlier factor**:

[image: incremental LOF]

**What is the best approach to translate that to a programming language?**

Your answer can also help me by pointing to articles that describe the symbols being used, the notation in general and tutorials on how to read and understand such papers.

Comment: translation-request is for human language to human language translation. More to the point, it heavily depends on what language. Say, it is not the same to do it in C or in *Brainf*ck*. Since math.se is not about programming, I would recommend doing it more general and answerable, or moving it to stackoverflow for the programming advice.

Comment: You basically want loops for every ∀ symbol, some function (or code in your current function, depends on how modular you want it) for every "compute this and that" and some assignments for every = symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking for what is generally described as part of a course in first-order predicate calculus.  A general introduction (including notation) can be found [here](http://www.fecundity.com/logic/) or in your library.

Generally, notation like [image] means "for all [image] that are in the set [image]..." and would often be implemented in programming language using a `for` loop or similar looping structure, depending on the particular language.

Introductory books on algorithms will also likely be useful in answering the questions you have.  An example would be Sedgewick's book **Algorithms in C** if your target computer language is C.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question can only be answered in a very broad sense. The pseudocode notation in algorithmic papers does not follow a consistent standard, and sometimes no pseudocode notation for the algorithms in question. A general advice would be to study the problem covered as much as possible and to get into mathematics a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have [written a translator](https://jarble.github.io/transpiler/javascript/js_transpiler/test_parser.html#%7B%22inputText%22%3A%22distance_formula(x1%2Cy1%2Cx2%2Cy2)%20%3D%20sqrt((x1-x2)%5E2%2B(y1-y2)%5E2)%22%2C%22inputLang%22%3A%22mathematical%20notation%22%2C%22outputLang%22%3A%22python%22%7D) that is able to convert some simple mathematical formulas into various programming languages. This is the input in in mathematical notation:

```
distance_formula(x1,y1,x2,y2) = sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2)
```

and this is the output in Python:

```
def distance_formula(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    return math.sqrt(((x1-x2)**2)+((y1-y2)**2))
```

Similarly, there are several [pseudocode translators](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pseudocode+translator%22) that have been designed to convert descriptions of algorithms into equivalent programs.